# Gson - Parse mixed types from Json

Tags: json, parsing, types, gson, mixed

I have a difficult for parse Json to JavaObject using Gson. Json is a mixed type content.

This is a Json :

```
[
[
    [
        "12",
        "COPLAT",
        "26/3/2015 11:23:34",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        ""
    ],
    [
        "11",
        "SEPARFI",
        "16/3/2015 10:44:50",
        "NA DATA DE HOJE, O REQUERENTE ASSINOU O TERMO DE ACORDO N. 031/2015 E QUITOU A 1. PARCELA DO PARCELAMENTO DE ISS.",
        "26/3/2015 11:12:47",
        "VANESSA CIMINI RIBEIRO SALGADO MISZPUTEN",
        "COPLAT",
        "26/3/2015 11:12:47"
    ]
],
{
    "PRO_nuProcesso": "9574",
    "PRO_aaProcesso": "2015",
    "PRO_dgProcesso": "85",
    "PRO_dlTitulo": "REQ.",
    "PRO_dtAbertura": "28/1/2015 16:07:21",
    "SIT_dcSituacao": "ATIVO",
    "SET_dcSetor": "COPOUP",
    "PRO_dcCaixaArquivo": "",
    "PRO_nmInteressado": "TABET LIMA & MARTINS LTDA",
    "PRO_dlAssunto": "PARCELAMENTO DE ISS - MOD. PRESTADOR"
}
```

]

this is a object Java:

```
public class Processo {
private String PRO_aaProcesso;
private String PRO_dcCaixaArquivo;
private String PRO_dgProcesso;
private String PRO_dlAssunto;
private String PRO_dlTitulo;
private String PRO_dtAbertura;
private String PRO_nmInteressado;
private String PRO_nuProcesso;
private String SET_dcSetor;
private String SIT_dcSituacao;

private String[][] andamentos;

public Processo(){
```

}

```
public Processo(String[][] andamentos, String PRO_aaProcesso, String PRO_dcCaixaArquivo, String PRO_dgProcesso, String PRO_dlAssunto, String PRO_dlTitulo, String PRO_dtAbertura, String PRO_nmInteressado, String PRO_nuProcesso, String SET_dcSetor, String SIT_dcSituacao) {
    this.PRO_aaProcesso = PRO_aaProcesso;
    this.PRO_dcCaixaArquivo = PRO_dcCaixaArquivo;
    this.PRO_dgProcesso = PRO_dgProcesso;
    this.PRO_dlAssunto = PRO_dlAssunto;
    this.PRO_dlTitulo = PRO_dlTitulo;
    this.PRO_dtAbertura = PRO_dtAbertura;
    this.PRO_nmInteressado = PRO_nmInteressado;
    this.PRO_nuProcesso = PRO_nuProcesso;
    this.SET_dcSetor = SET_dcSetor;
    this.SIT_dcSituacao = SIT_dcSituacao;
    this.andamentos = andamentos;
}
```

Getters / Setters 
}

This is a Parse :

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
    List<Processo> postsList = Arrays.asList(gson.fromJson(testeJsonCompleto,
                Processo[].class));
```

This a exception:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY

Tks for help !!

Comment: there is somthing missing in json it's not a valid according to http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Comment: He's missing a "]" for the closing of the parent array, also the exception occurs because there are two type of objects inside the parent array, one is an array, another one is an object.